# Running the batch file using gitlab ci and getting the output

Tags: batch-file, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have set up my gitlab project with two files: one with a batch file which just prints `hello world` the other file is `.gitlab-ci.yml` file which executes the pipeline.

The code in the batch file is:

```
ECHO OFF
ECHO 'Hello World'
PAUSE
```

The gitlab-ci.yml file has the test stage:

```
test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo 'test'
        - chmod +x ./hello-world.bat
```

When I make any changes the pipeline starts and executes successfully, but I am not getting the required output from the batch file. I am missing something here?

The pipeline result looks like this:

[image: pipeline-result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am using the gitlab-ci runner on windows I created a python script and pushed that to the self-hosted github instance. In that python script, I just triggered the .bat script which then runs and shows the output in the project pipeline.

The script looks like this:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call([r'C:\hello.bat'])
```

That is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you're only adding +x permissions to the file making it executable, but never actually running it.

If you modify your gitlab-ci.yml to:

```
test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo 'test'
        - chmod +x ./hello-world.bat
        - ./hello-world.bat
```

That being said, I'm not 100% sure this is going to work. Since this seems to be running on a linux system, and .bat scripts are intended for windows based systems. 
Please refer to bash scripts on how these work.

Comment: worked for me, just remove the `./` in the front